# Picasso не грузит в while

Tags: android, многопоточность, while, picasso

Всем привет.
Хочу получать одну и туже картинку циклом, но если ставлю 
`while(true){.....}` хоть `contentButton.setOnClickListener` хоть  `ThreadConnectedWIFI` в run перед handler отказывается работать, ну как отказывается срабатывает `System.out.println("Thread");` и все, картинка не срабатывает.

Может проблема тут

> W/Settings: Setting airplane_mode_on has moved from
>   android.provider.Settings.System to android.provider.Settings.Global,
>   returning read-only value.

вылетает вот такая

> W/art: Suspending all threads took

картинка обновляется если быстро нажимать кнопку

**P.S.** но обновление происходит 2 - 6 секунд хотя нажимаю несколько раз в секунду (на это пофиг, может связь такая).

Плиз помогите 4 день роюсь и не могу найти хоть какую то инфо по этой проблеме с `while`.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {
    Button contentButton;
    private Handler mUiHandler = new Handler();
    private ImageSwitcher imageSwitcher;
    ThreadConnectedWIFI ThreadConnectedWIFI;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        imageSwitcher = (ImageSwitcher)findViewById(R.id.imageSwitcher1);
        imageSwitcher.setFactory(new ViewSwitcher.ViewFactory() {
            @Override
            public View makeView() {
                ImageView myView = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());
                myView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
                myView.setLayoutParams(new ImageSwitcher.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                return myView;
            }
        });
        contentButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.contentButton);
        contentButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                ImageSwitcherPicasso mImageSwitcherPicasso = new ImageSwitcherPicasso(MainActivity.this, imageSwitcher);
                Picasso.with(MainActivity.this)
                        .load("ссылка")
                        .memoryPolicy(MemoryPolicy.NO_CACHE )
                        .networkPolicy(NetworkPolicy.NO_CACHE)
                        .resize(1024, 1024)
                        .into(mImageSwitcherPicasso);
            }
        });
        ThreadConnectedWIFI = new ThreadConnectedWIFI();
        ThreadConnectedWIFI.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

    }

    public class ImageSwitcherPicasso implements Target {

        private ImageSwitcher mImageSwitcher;
        private Context mContext;

        public ImageSwitcherPicasso(Context context, ImageSwitcher imageSwitcher){
            mImageSwitcher = imageSwitcher; mContext = context;
        }
        @Override
        public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom loadedFrom) {
            mImageSwitcher.setImageDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(mContext.getResources(), bitmap));
        }
        @Override public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable drawable) { }
        @Override public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable drawable) { }
    } // выводит изображение полученной из дополнительного потока

    private class ThreadConnectedWIFI extends Thread{ // Поток загрузки изображений

        @Override
        public void run() {
            super.run();
            mUiHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    System.out.println("Thread");
                    ImageSwitcherPicasso mImageSwitcherPicasso = new ImageSwitcherPicasso(MainActivity.this, imageSwitcher);
                    Picasso.with(MainActivity.this)
                            .load("ccылка")
                            .memoryPolicy(MemoryPolicy.NO_CACHE )
                            .networkPolicy(NetworkPolicy.NO_CACHE)
                            .resize(1024, 1024)
                            .into(mImageSwitcherPicasso);
                }
            });
        }
    } // Поток - приём и отправка данных через WIFI
}
```

Comment: Зачем получать одну и ту же картинку в цикле? Что вы хотите в итоге получить?

Comment: фото с камеры, rtsp поток с камеры обработать не могу, за сервер платить как то не хочется.